# How do I get an if else statement embedded in a for loop to choose one option over another if ANY of the submissions to the if statement are true?

Tags: r

I am working with microarray data within an ExpressionSet object downloaded from Gene Expression Omnibus. The rows of the expression data in this object are labeled with probe names, but for downstream analysis I really need the gene symbols.

Thankfully, the individuals that compiled this dataset included the corresponding gene symbols in the metadata that accompanies this kind of object.

I am trying to write a for loop within a function that looks at the list of variable labels (effectively row names for the metadata), determines whether a column called "GENE_SYMOBL" is present, then either writes those gene symbols to a vector, or moves on and converts the probe names to gene symbols using gprofileR.

I don't want my if else statement to run for each iteration of my for loop, I just want it to run after the if statement has determined if any of the row names are "GENE_SYMBOL".

So far I have written the for loop with the if statement but can't figure out how to put the condition if ANY of the column names match, then do A, if none match then do B.

```r
nums <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncos = 27, nrow = 12))
feature_headers <- c(letters, "GENE_SYMBOL")
colnames(nums) <- feature_headers

for (i in 1:length(feature_headers)) {

 if(feature_headers[i] == "GENE_SYMBOL") {

   gene_symb <- nums[["GENE_SYMBOL"]]

 }else{

   #what else it does is more involved that this question needs be so
   #I just wrote out something for the function to say
  cat("boohoo no genes for you"\n)
  }
}
```

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated and let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific situation, R has a handy %in% operator that you can use to check this:

```
if ("GENE_SYMBOL" %in% feature_headers) {
    #...
}
```

As a more general rule, if your goal is "if loop A meets condition B, then do action C", you can follow this pattern:

```
found <- FALSE
for (loopStatement) {
    if(condition) {
        found <- TRUE
        break
    }
}
if(found) {
    doActionC()
}
```

This way, if you get through the whole list without finding the label, `found` is still `FALSE`- but if you do find the label, you don't do a bunch of unnecessary checking. This is essentially the gist of what's happening under the hood with `%in%`, and `%in%` is faster to write and probably faster to process. It's a good thing to know for other situations, though.

Also, the `%in%` operator can be [used to check](http://dr-k-lo.blogspot.com/2013/11/in-in-r-underused-in-operator.html) if the elements of one list are shared with another list!

Comment: That's what I was looking for... I completely forgot %in% existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean variable to record if your condition is hit in the for loop and then break to avoid unnecessary calculation

```
nums <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncos = 27, nrow = 12))
feature_headers <- c(letters, "GENE_SYMBOL")
colnames(nums) <- feature_headers

FALSE -> found

for (i in 1:length(feature_headers)) {
 if(feature_headers[i] == "GENE_SYMBOL") {
   TRUE -> found
   break
 }
}
if (found) {
    dosomething()
}
else {
    dosomethingelse()
}
```